# Parsing a string with NumberFormat

Tags: java, formatting, number-formatting, decimalformat

From the this java [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29)

> parse
>
> public abstract Number parse(String source,
>              ParsePosition parsePosition)
>
> Returns a Long if possible (e.g., within the range [Long.MIN_VALUE,
>   Long.MAX_VALUE] and with no decimals), otherwise a Double. If
>   IntegerOnly is set, will stop at a decimal point (or equivalent; e.g.,
>   for rational numbers "1 2/3", will stop after the 1). Does not throw
>   an exception; if no object can be parsed, index is unchanged!

*(or equivalent; e.g., for rational numbers "1 2/3", will stop after the 1)*

What are they talkng about? is it something possible at all parsing such a String? 
However I have tried also with `setParseIntegerOnly(false);` and it parses only **1**.
What did they mean with that statement that I must have missed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says clearly that Parse() works to get a number from the string. In case of a rational number like "1 2/3" (read one and two by three) it will parse this string as 1 (after which it reads a space and ignores everything thereafter)

Comment: @ManojAwasthi please read my question again

Answer (score 0):

The parsing will stop at the following:

1. Decimal point when IntegerOnly is set
2. Space in a rational number

Comment: could you give me an example? of parsing rational numbers in like 2/3? Also without space does not work

Comment: @Rollerball There is no trivial class in java that represent Rational numbers.

Comment: @Rollerball Why wrong? they say that the case of IntegerOnly is equivalent to the case of rationl - in both cases parsing is not full but is stopped in the agreed character.

Comment: they say:If `IntegerOnly is set`which implies that if not it behaves otherwise. Furthermore is not clear why `2/3` is mentioned at all as there is no way to parse it. (in any case).

Comment: @Rollerball They say:If IntegerOnly is set OR equivalent rational number that cannot be parsed, e.g. 2/3... because it cannot be parsed only 1 will be parsed...